# Hasura use SSL certificates for Postgres connection

Tags: postgresql, ssl, hasura

I can run Hashura from the Docker image.

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \
  -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://username:password@hostname:port/dbname \
  -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true \
  hasura/graphql-engine:latest
```

But I also have a Postgres instance that can only be accessed with three certificates:

```
psql "sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=server-ca.pem \
      sslcert=client-cert.pem sslkey=client-key.pem \
      hostaddr=$DB_HOST \
      port=$DB_PORT\
      user=$DB_USER dbname=$DB_NAME"
```

I don't see a configuration for Hasura that allows me to connect to a Postgres instance in such a way.

Is this something I'm suppose to pass into the database connection URL?

How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to mount your certificates into the docker container and then configure libpq (which is what hasura uses underneath) to use the required certificates with these [environment variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html). It'll be something like this (I haven't tested this):

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 \
  -v /absolute-path-of-certs-folder:/certs
  -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL=postgres://hostname:port/dbname \
  -e HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE=true \
  -e PGSSLMODE=verify-ca \
  -e PGSSLCERT=/certs/client-cert.pem \
  -e PGSSLKEY=/certs/client-key.pem \
  -e PGSSLROOTCERT=/certs/server-ca.pem \
  hasura/graphql-engine:latest
```